# change model property by another property django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have model `Word`

```
class Word(models.Model): 
   group_id = models.IntegerField()
   old_group_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have some word query:

```
words = Word.objects.filter(...)
```

Right now I want every word to set  `old_group_id` to `group_id` 
something like `words.update(old_group_id=group_id)`
So far I am doing it by iterating through every word, but this doesn't feel very effective:

```
for word in words:
  word.old_group_id = word.group_id
  word.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using an **`F(..)`** expression:

```
from django.db.models import F

Word.objects.filter(...).update(old_group_id=F('group_id'))
```

An [**`F`**-expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) is a way to refer to a model field, instead of using a value (you can also use double underscores to look "through" relations).

The above will thus result in a query like:

```
UPDATE word
SET old_group_id = group_id
WHERE ...
```

The update is thus done *at the database level*. So there is no iteration involved at the Django/Python side. This will thus (nearly) always outperform changing the model object at the Django/Python layer: it reduces the amount of queries from *O(n)* to *O(1)*, and furthermore databases are usually optimized to do updates "in bulk".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`F` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

```
words.update(old_group_id=F('group_id'))
```